# Where does this inaccuracy with DOM scroll events come from?

Tags: javascript, dom, scroll

Have a look at the code below, there is a jsbin for it too here: http://output.jsbin.com/qosevogeka/

```js
var container = document.querySelector('.container')
var firstEventHandled = false
container.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  if (firstEventHandled) return
  console.log(e.target.scrollLeft)
  firstEventHandled = true
})
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.box {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 40%;
  height: 50px;
  background: yellow;
}

.box+.box {
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box">
    </div>
    <div class="box">
    </div>
    <div class="box">
    </div>
    <div class="box">
    </div>
    <div class="box">
    </div>
    <div class="box">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

If you scroll the resulting view, you will see that `0` is never logged to the scroll which I expect since the `scrollLeft` was `0` before I started scrolling. Where does this inaccuracy with the scroll events come from? Thanks

Comment: By the time the event fires the scroll has already happened, so it's not at 0.

Answer (score 2):

> Where does this inaccuracy with the scroll events come from? Thanks

As per [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/scroll)

> The scroll event is fired when the document view or an element has
>   been scrolled.

So this line

```
console.log(e.target.scrollLeft)
```

is logging the `e.target.scrollLeft` **after the scroll has happened**, since this function is an event-handler which is executed after the event has happened already. And by definition, **once the scroll has happened you cannot be at the starting point**.

> If you scroll the resulting view, you will see that 0 is never logged
>   to the scroll which I expect since the scrollLeft was 0 before I
>   started scrolling

Unfortunately, there is no event called *scrollstart* like `dragstart` or `mousedown` or `keydown`, **so there is no way to know when the scroll had started** and we only know once the scroll has happened.

Comment: `[...]since this function is an event-handler which is executed after the event has happened already[...]`, most of the DOM events (except e.g.  the `scroll` event)  are `cancelable` and then their default behavior can be prevented. So it is not obvious, that `e.target.scrollLeft` changes before the event propagation finished.

Comment: @t.niese `most of the DOM events (except e.g. the scroll event) are cancelable and then their default behavior can be prevented`, not `scroll` though, because it happens after the fact, as stated in the answer.

Comment: @t.niese it's not related to event propagation anyways, because there's a single event handler attached. this is the default behavior, which is not cancelable in this case.

Comment: @AndréWerlang In my comment I said that `scroll` is not `cancelable`. For an inexperienced developer it might not be obvious that certain events like `wheel` and `keydown` are cancelable and therefor the browser has to wait for the end of the propagation, to determin if some actions have to/can be done and others are not  cancelable,  and therefor the changes are instantly applied to the DOM.